# Streaming mp4 with vlc to html browser

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, vlc

I have problems streaming my webcam picture (without sound) to a html page. I'm using the latest (v2.0.2 vlc for windows) for streaming, here's the command line:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy  dshow:// --dshow-vdev="Logitech QuickCam Chat" --dshow-adev=none --dshow-caching=0 --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,channels=1,ab=128,samplerate=44100,width=320}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/webcam.mp4}
```

when I open the stream in another vlc player (http://127.0.0.1:8080/webcam.mp4), I can watch the stream, but when I'm trying to embedding it to a webpage, I can see nothing! here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="video" class="projekktor" autoplay="autoplay" width="300px" preload="metadata">  
      <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/webcam.mp4" />
            Your browser doesn't appear to support the HTML5 <code>&lt;video&gt;</code> element.  
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Than I'm trying to open it in the browser like:

```
file:///C:/videostreaming/video.html
```

What I can see in chrome example, is that there's network traffic, the stream is downloading, but nothing displayed.

Comment: Did you ever get this problem solved? I am having a similar problem and would love to know how you solved it.

Comment: @cssyphus No, I haven't, but if you will be able, please don't forget to answer this question. :)

Comment: @balazs I am having the exact same problem but I haven't found the answer on this page.   Has there been any progress?

Answer (score 19):

You can't transmit mp4 over http protocol using VLC

Follow this link to see the Output method / muxer matrix
http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html

However you can try to transcode to ogg.

Try this:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" \
-I dummy  dshow:// --dshow-vdev="Logitech QuickCam Chat" \
--dshow-adev=none --dshow-caching=0 \
--sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=1024,channels=1,ab=128,samplerate=44100,width=320}:http{dst=:8080/webcam.ogg}
```

and in your html video tag:

```
<source src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/webcam.ogg"/>
```

Comment: Is it possible to supply a rtmp stream to -I input instead of webcam?

Answer (score 3):

try adding the type of video (type="video/mp4"):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: if that doesn't work you can try converting it to ogg video. vlc also does that and its html5 video-able

Comment: looks like from my chrome that mine is coming through as an application/octet-stream.  I don't think it will show up unless it sees it as a video/mp4. you can go to the advanced preferences of VLC and in the HTML streaming option set the MIME type to video/mp4

Comment: setting the MIME type to video/mp4 either don't solve the problem. When I streaming using theora (video/ogg) the MIME is application/octet-stream too, and it works. But I would like to streaming mp4 format.

Answer (score 1):

you're telling VLC to stream in TS format `mux=ts` this is your problem, you need to mux in mp4

Comment: mp4 is not an valid options for mux (http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html).

Answer (score 1):

For live streaming you should use following

```
<video id="video" src="http://localhost:8181/stream" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora" autoplay="autoplay"/>
```

More at 
Here's [a link](https://ipcamtalk.com/threads/how-to-use-vlc-to-transcode-ip-video-to-an-html5-compatible-format.1371/)!

Please note: Video type "ogg" only!