# vlc mp4 stream to html5 player

Tags: html, streaming, mp4, vlc

I would like to stream my desktop to some other devices like ps3, tablet or smartTV.

The simplest solution for this I thought was vlc streaming to a html5 page stored on a local server. I start vlc in my commandline with the following transcode settings:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100,scale=0,acodec=mpga,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=:8080}
```

The html code:

```
<video width="704" height="396" controls="controls" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="http://####:8080/" type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I can watch the stream into vlc on a different machine. According to this post:

[Streaming mp4 with vlc to html browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294836/streaming-mp4-with-vlc-to-html-browser)

`mux=mp4` won't create a working stream. Also reported in the [vlc manual](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html#id346006). Unless I am mistaken they define `ts` as the right mux for h264.

So where is the clue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use mp4 mux format to pack h264 encoded video. You must use asf or ts mux. Ts and asf not working with html5 video player. Use vlc plugin to play video or change video codec to other such theora...