# Streaming a MP4 file over http and watching it

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

I have a MP4 file (H.264 + MP3). I want to stream it over http protocol so I can watch it through an address like http://127.0.0.1/test.mp4. I tried VLC to stream the file but I could not see the stream when I tried to watch it in another VLC program (this time as a client). What configuration should I use? Is there any other app (component) for this purpose?

Update: In fact, I am trying to stream the file via a programming. But, before using vlc components in my code. I just want to run the whole scenario with the vlc itself. There has been similar questions like [Streaming mp4 with vlc to html browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294836/streaming-mp4-with-vlc-to-html-browser?rq=1) but they were streaming a webcam.

Comment: A bit unclear question and not about programming. If you want to stream MP4, put the file on a web server and make sure it's in proper format (MOOV atom in the beginning) and off you go.

Comment: In fact, I am trying to stream the file via a programming. But, before using vlc components in my code. I just want to run the whole scenario with the vlc itself. There has been similar questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294836/streaming-mp4-with-vlc-to-html-browser?rq=1 but they were streaming a webcam. Mine, I think, must be even easier.