# Html5 player no plugin needed

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, web-deployment

please help me guys this is my code and it works fine with me on the pc browsers but it need plugin to play it. I searched and tried a lot of methods to play this link live stream video but all of them are failed. This is the only code that plays the channel on the pc browsers and i need someone to help me or re-write the code so that can be played on pc and mobile devices browsers.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<object id='mediaPlayer1' width="640" height="360"
  classid='clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6'
  codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701'
  standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-oleobject'>
  <param name='fileName' value="http://168.187.49.14:8080" />
  <param name='animationatStart' value='true' />
  <param name='transparentatStart' value='true' />
  <param name='autoStart' value="false" />
  <param name='showControls' value="true" />
  <param name ="ShowAudioControls"value="true" />
  <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
  <param name='loop' value="false" />
  <embed type='application/x-mplayer2'
  pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
  id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1'
  bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1'
  showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="640" height="360"
  src="http://168.187.49.14:8080" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="false"> </embed>
  </object>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use HMTL5 video tag ?

Comment: I tried it. It useless I cant see the video!

Comment: It's not useless. Youtube uses it. Is your video available on a public domain. If yes then post a link to sample video.

Comment: To use the `video` tag, the video needs to be an MP4, OGG or WEBM. MP4 has the best support among browsers.

Comment: amduglas- it is mp4 link but it not show on the mobiles browsers. can you help please and test my video link ?

Comment: I don't see any reference to an MP4 link in your post.

Comment: @iangetz it is mp4 format but the player cannot define it maybe because the link is ended with port http://168.187.49.14:8080

Comment: What technology are you using to host your "live stream" video?

Comment: I use OPS and VLC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming mp4 with vlc to html browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294836/streaming-mp4-with-vlc-to-html-browser)