# How to play UDP stream on browser?

Tags: udp, video-streaming

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I have a question: I want to make an online TV website. I've got the UDP streaming links for each TV channels (ex. udp://@225.1.2.249:30120). Then, I can't find the way how to play that stream on video player in browsers. (I've already tried Video.js and hls.js but both not work, but it easily play on VLC).
I know that my grammar is terrible, hope you forgive that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming mp4 with vlc to html browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294836/streaming-mp4-with-vlc-to-html-browser)

Comment: Read the first answer please

Comment: You mean I can't transmit mp4 over http protocol?

Answer (score 4):

You don’t. Browsers support HTTP, Websockets, and webrtc. Any other protocol requires a browser plugin.